# remote: -----> Python app detected remote: ! Requested runtime (Python 3.6.4) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python 3.6.4) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to sreeman-billing.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/sreeman-billing.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sreeman-billing.git'
```

i have found many answers to this question so i have changed the version to the stable version that heroku supports but heruko isnt taking the version from runtime file instead it detecting the version automatically 
please can someone  suggest me any way to make this work

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's taking it from your `runtime.txt` file. It specifically says "requested runtime". How are you updating that file? What version are you trying to use (please show us the exact contents of the file)?

Comment: python-3.6.5
this is the version in runtime.txt where the runtime file is located parallel to manage,py and requirements in  the app root folder

Comment: And have you committed that change and pushed it to Heroku? Are you working in the `master` branch?

Comment: Oh, and are you using `pip` (with a `requirements.txt`) or `pipenv` (with `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`)? If you have all three files `pipenv` will take precedence.

Comment: ya i have pushed everything to master branch

Comment: sorry ,i didnt get the last thing you have said  my bad ,please could you make that clear

Comment: Which of those three files are present in your root directory (`requirements.txt`, `Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185301/discussion-between-mounikes-mintu-and-chris).